# Iterate over dictionary feature in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop

My requirement is to print out the following mapping via Python Dictionary feature from range (1, 60) iterating over for loop. Basically I want the output which maps 1 to 10001, maps 2 to 10002.........maps 60 to 10060

`{ 1: 10001, 2: 10002, 3: 10003, 4: 10004`
`….`
`….`
`58: 10058, 59: 10059, 60: 10060 }`

I'm new to Dictionary feature. Can anyone help me out to return something like above ?

Comment: `my_dic = dict(zip(range(1, 61), range(10001, 10061))` try it.

Comment: Use this: `{i:i+10000 for i in range(1,61)}`  That's a dict comprehension.  No need to use zip or multiple ranges for this.

Comment: Do you have this dictionary and want to print it, or do you want to create this dictionary ? Please provide code sample and expected output.

Comment: @TomKarzes why avoid those? Probably faster and pretty readable IMO

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The main reason is clarity.  There are two parameters:  60 and 10000.  My version is more concise, and uses each parameter once.  You'd have to work to get it wrong.  The dict/zip version uses 60 twice (61 and 10061) and 10000 twice (10001 and 10061).  You have to work *not* to get it wrong.  That being said, mine is faster with Python 2, yours in Python 3 (the dict comprehension got slower in Python 3, and the dict/zip got faster).  Not sure why comprehensions are slower than they used to be.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with dict comprehensions

```
d = {i: i + 10000 for i in range(1, 61)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fast, clean variant using [*zip()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
dict(zip(range(1, 61), range(10_001, 10_061)))
```

Stylistically, it might be nice to use [*itertools.count()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) for the second part:

```
dict(zip(range(1, 61), count(10_001)))
```

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for key, value in your_dictionary.items():
    print(f"{key} is mapped to {value}")
```